# Two files are found in WATIR-Classic 3.0.0 but not in WATIR-Classic 3.7.0

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I can find two files named 'testcase.rb' and 'assertions.rb' in WATIR-CLASSIC 3.0.0, but those two files are not found in WATIR-CLASSIC 3.7.0.  What is the reason for this? Or is it found in some other folder?

Answer (score 0):

In `watir-classic 3.0.0`, the [`testcase.rb`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-classic/3.0.0/Watir/TestCase) and [`assertion.rb`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-classic/3.0.0/Watir/Assertions) files define the `Watir::TestCase` and `Watir::Assertions` classes.  These classes provide a subset of the functionality found in `Test::Unit`.

Per this [commit](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/commit/aed96dc56d2def942142e07323c6f2b65d1e9920), these files were deleted in `watir-classic 3.1.0`.  Since there are a number of feature-rich testing frameworks--from `MiniTest` to `rspec`--there's really no need to include a parallel framework in the `watir-classic` gem.

Comment: hi Thanks, When you say  "ruby's built-in MiniTest", Can you please point out to me from which Ruby version this is available? Which Ruby version this is not available?  When can I found the verification methods provided by Watir-classic  ?

Comment: I've edited the answer and removed the "built-in" statement since `MiniTest` was included in `Std-lib` starting in ruby 1.9 but [removed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9711) from `Stl-lib` in 2.2.0 (as was `TestUnit`).

Comment: hi, Thanks  but how about this assertion.rb? The assertion file which comes with water-classic 3.0.0 contains the verification methods, Where can I find that?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [MiniTest::Assertions](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html)

Comment: No no,  I know of this module very well, What I am asking is, there is method named 'verify' which was provided by Watir-classic 3.0.0, Where can I find corresponding method in the recent version of test-unit 3.0.9?